# Beamer: AtBeginSection and insertsubsectionnavigation

Tags: beamer

I'm trying to get a presentation which has for each section a leading slide which shows the name of the current section as well as a table of the subsections belonging to this section.

The first part is easy, I'm using

```
\AtBeginSection[]%
{%
\begin{frame}[plain]%
  \begin{center}%
    \usebeamerfont{section title}\insertsection%
  \end{center}%
\end{frame}%
```

However trying to use the `\insertsubsectionnavigation` command to insert the subsection table fails (maybe due to the fact that this command is meant to be used in templates?).

Is there anyway to get beamer to display the table for me, or do I have to re-create the code used for the `\insertsubsectionnavigation` command?

EDIT:

Okay, scratch that, after putting the insertsection and the insertsubsectionnavigation in beamercolorboxes they both show up, now I just have to figure out how to make them look good :-)

Comment: somewhat offtopic: how do I mark this question as answered (see later edit above)?

Comment: When you can, write an answer (click "answer your own question") and then mark it as accepted. Then when others search for something similar, they will find your answer.

Comment: I can't mark an unanswered question as answered. Please mark your edits a little bit clearer, otherwise there are difficult to spot. If you find the answer by yourself, post it as an answer and mark it. But normally you should wait a little.

Comment: okay, I've edited my edit to mark it better and next time I'll wait longer to get a better answer than my own!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note that `beamer` can do this out-of-the-box:

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[sectionstyle=show/hide,subsectionstyle=hide/show/hide]
  \end{frame}
  \addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}% If you don't want them to affect the slide number
}
```

See the `beamer` manual, page 100, section 10.5 "Adding a Table of Contents", for more information.

Comment: Okay, I think I need more coffee, that is of course a much easier solution to my problem. Although I now have to figure out how to supress the normal "ball" in front of the section name. Or to be more accurate I have to figure out what format I actually want for these section slides, just the section name with a table of the subsections below it (that was the original idea) or simply a table of contents with the current section and subsections highlighted.

Comment: Just to answer my own "question" (again), the style of the toc can be changed by using a `\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}[default]`.